# Source undefined in jquery-ui.js when using Autocomplete widget

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I used this code for autocomplete in scripts.js.coffee in rails app.

```
$(function() {
  var script;
  script = gon.scripts;
  return $("#search").autocomplete({
    source: script
  });
});
```

My controller has this line

```
gon.scripts = Script.all.map(&:title)
```

In the JavaScript web console I am seeing this error:

```
this.source is undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but the autocomplete plugin does not assign the source from the options object passed in when first constructing it.

So instead of:

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
  source: script
});
```

you should have:

```
$("#search").autocomplete();
$("#search").autocomplete("option", "source", script);
```

This will set this.source to the right value.